# Deploying Android Application in market

Tags: android, google-play

If I have an app on the market with analytics API integrated , now  i want to change the  integrated API (analytics) to some other analytics API and update the build in market. I want the user forcefully to update the application. How can i do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Nothing is impossible but it's illegal if the user haven't clicked "Automatic update" for your app.

Answer (score 2):

If your app uploaded on android market, and you update ur application with incremental version code. Users of application will be notified with update for application, **but by no means** user can be ask to update application forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force users to update, unless the functionality of the app is reliant on something external (eg, a call to an URL) that you can deliberately break at the external end -- and even then, they could just uninstall the app instead of upgrading.